# PDO installation - enable pdo_mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I surfed a lot and a lot, many have same problem. no answer have solved my problem , this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724712/checked-the-php-ini-file-extension-php-pdo-mysql-dll-enabled-but-still-error) is the closest one.it's answer didn't help me. I can't comment over answer to get more details. I need 10 more reputation to do that. I'm using appserv I've changed the setting required in php.ini

```
            extension=php_pdo.dll
            extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
            extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
            extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
            extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
            extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
            extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
            extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
            extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

and phpinfo() still showing only this:

[image: phpinfo()]

I still have same error:

"could not find driver"

I wanna add the pdo for mysql as well.
what the right, complete and simple way to make it works? 
I made this [tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) too.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache server?

Comment: Did you check that you have those extensions? Search for `extension_dir` in `phpinfo()` and check that directory.

Comment: Please make your question more clear, then add some information on your environment.

Comment: @JayBlanchard what do u mean by restarting the Apache ? I tried to use _php.exe_ to install it it gives me error that OCI.dll is missing but all _.dll_ files are fine

Comment: @Furgas yes dear i have them

Comment: You have to restart the server each time you make changes to the PHP configuration. What server are you running?

Comment: I'm using Appserv localhost, Apache.

Comment: Restart Apache and then check to see if the PDO is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a day of research, I found my problem!
this may be useful for new developers:
it works for me using `Appserv 2.5.10` on Windows 8:

1. first make sure that you edit the right `php.ini` file. Do that by going to view the phpinfo(), search for **Configuration File (php.ini) Path** in the info page, you will find the directory that you need to configure the file in
2. after Editing the `php.ini` file, save the changes and restart your device

at first i didn't now how to restart the Apache, i thought it might be a `cmd` command or clicking a patch file. but it raises errors for me when i used `apache_start.bat` patch. restarting the PC will do fine!